# Select the latest date, from dates that differ from each other by no more than x minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have a two problems, I'm actually working on some data in Postgres (but if you can resolve it in e.g. in MySQL, it will be helpful also), and at this moment I need to do this things:

1. Group dates that differ from each other no more than x minutes (e.g. 15 minutes)
2. From each of group of dates which we get in previous step select the latest one. (I think I can solve this problem myself ;] ), but any help will be appreciated.

I hope that I write quite clearly what I want to do :)

I look for some solution to my problems, but I found a lot of question and answers to grouping date by day or minutes, but it isn't that what I want, and isn't helpful at any way :)

Sample dates:

```
2016-10-15 11:29:06+02:00
2016-10-15 11:29:09+02:00
2016-10-15 11:29:15+02:00
2016-10-15 11:29:24+02:00
2016-10-15 12:41:11+02:00
2016-10-15 12:41:13+02:00
2016-10-15 12:41:15+02:00
2016-10-15 12:41:17+02:00
2016-10-15 12:41:28+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:04+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:07+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:09+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:11+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:17+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:19+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:21+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:25+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:28+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:29+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:30+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:02+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:03+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:04+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:07+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:09+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:11+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:13+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:14+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:17+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:21+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:23+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:25+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:00+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:02+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:03+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:05+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:07+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:09+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:11+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:13+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:15+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:16+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:19+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:22+02:00
2016-10-15 17:50:05+02:00
2016-10-15 17:50:06+02:00
2016-10-15 17:50:07+02:00
2016-10-15 17:50:12+02:00
2016-10-15 17:50:17+02:00
2016-10-15 17:50:26+02:00
2016-10-15 17:50:37+02:00
2016-10-15 17:50:41+02:00
2016-10-19 12:13:23+02:00
2016-10-19 12:13:33+02:00
2016-10-19 12:13:42+02:00
2016-10-19 13:39:55+02:00
2016-10-19 13:40:05+02:00
```

The expected results (something like that) :

```
2016-10-15 11:29:24+02:00
2016-10-15 12:41:28+02:00
2016-10-15 13:51:30+02:00
2016-10-15 15:12:25+02:00
2016-10-15 16:31:22+02:00
2016-10-15 17:50:41+02:00
2016-10-19 12:13:42+02:00
2016-10-19 13:40:05+02:00
```

Comment: By "postgis", I assume you mean Postgres.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, of course ! :)

Comment: There is an edit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the list of dates where the *next* date is more than 15 minutes away.  This is simplest to solve in Postgres:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(dte) over (order by dte) as next_dte
      from t
     ) t
where next_dte is NULL or next_dte > dte + interval '15 minute';
```

In either database, you can do this using `not exists` as well:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.dte > t.dte and t2.dte < date_add(t.dte, interval 15 minute)
                 );
```

I used MySQL syntax for the date arithmetic in this version.

Comment: It works like a charm! Perfectly! Thank you very much Gordon! :)